# Keras: Get predict result and intermediate layer value at the same time

Tags: keras, output, predict

I want to get the results of the last layer which is the category label and the intermediate layer value at the same time, for example, after I call `model.predict()`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer to this post should point you in the right direction:

[multiple-outputs-in-keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036971/multiple-outputs-in-keras)

You will likely need to use Keras' functional API for this as you can specify multiple inputs and outputs.

[Keras Functional API Guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/)