# Implementing a custom loss function for object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, object-detection

I am new to keras and tensorflow . How do I go about implementing a custom loss function while doing object detection , right now I have 5 parameters -  4 for bounding box coordinates and 1 for whether the object is present or not . **Loss function should return square of difference between coordinates if object is present else if object is absent it should return a huge value as loss** .  This is the code I am tring right now:

```
def loss_func(y_true,y_pred):
  mask = np.array([False, False, False,False,True])   # check column of the class of object
  mask1 = np.array([True, True, True,True,False])     # get the columns of the coordinates of B box
  check_class = K.mean(K.square(tf.subtract(tf.boolean_mask(y_true,mask),tf.boolean_mask(y_pred,mask))))
  mean_square = K.mean(K.square(tf.subtract(tf.boolean_mask(y_true,mask1),tf.boolean_mask(y_pred,mask1))))
  value=K.mean(tf.boolean_mask(y_pred,mask))

  return value*mean_square + check_class
```

Here I am masking other values to obtain the last value which is 1000--> object present 0 --> object absent.
Is there any other better way to do this?

The value of loss when I am running this in Kaggle decreases rapidly , by 2nd epoch the loss becomes 0.

Comment: Are you using batches of size 1? (assuming so as you use mask of size 5)

Comment: No batch size is not 1 , I thought loss function will be calculated for each image? Infact batch size is 16

Comment: @Or Dinari I changed the batch size to 1 , now the loss is just 0 - no change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all i would recommend using 1 and not 1000 for the "image exist" parameter.
You can manipulate y_true and y_pred.

```
penalty = 100

def lf(y_true,y_pred):
    mean_square = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true[:,0:4], y_pred[:,0:4])
    check_class = tf.subtract(y_true[:,4], y_pred[:,4])
    check_class = check_class * -penalty
    check_class = tf.keras.backend.mean(check_class)
    return mean_square + check_class
```

The above function first check the mean squared error for the first 4 parameters.

the second part then check for the "present" parameter.

If they are different it will output -1, if they are the same it will output 0.

Then it use the penalty for punishing it for a wrong parameter.

Using "punish" by some constant can be difficult to train. I would recommend changing the optimizer to **SGD**, adam will not work well in the situation, and playing with the penalty until you reach satisfying results.

Comment: @Or Dinari , is it possible to avoid the mean_square term if the class isn't 1. Also, do you recommend to try to same code on SGD? (PS: the activation function is ReLU)

Comment: @Kitwradr Yes. batch size won't matter.

Comment: @Shobhit Kumar, You can use any loss function which you prefer, if you prefer something different then Mean Square. And regarding SGD, I would only use SGD for this case, from my experience different optimizers does not work well with 'punishment' such as the above. Generally, I think the right solution will be to have 2 heads for the output (the 4 parameters, and the 'present'), this will allow you to use different activation function and loss functions with ease. However it depends on the domain, so it might not be the best solution.

Comment: how can i set two heads for the output in keras with different loss and activation functions? i think this would be perfect

Comment: @ShobhitKumar This is an extensive tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/04/keras-multiple-outputs-and-multiple-losses/  , and here is some Toy example from stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036971/multiple-outputs-in-keras

Comment: thanks... i have now split the output into a dense(of size 4) for the box and dense of size one for the class. However, is it possible to ignore the dense loss of size four when the class is zero?(that is no object, so i dont want a box)

Comment: @ShobhitKumar You will need the box head to have the present bit as well, and write a custom loss function for it, you can look into tf.cond, could be helpful.

Comment: @Or Dinari Thanks a lot for your help. i was able to create my network successfully