# Accuracy on middle layer of autoencoder implemente using Keras

Tags: keras, metrics, autoencoder

I have implemented an autoencoder using Keras. I understand that I can add accuracy performance metric as follows:

> autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', 
>                       loss='mean_squared_error', 
>                       metrics=['accuracy'])

My question is:
Is the accuracy metric applied on the last layer of the decoder by default? If so, how can I set it so that it would get the representations from middle (hidden) layer to compute accuracy performance? Do I need to define a custom metric? How would that work?

Comment: The accuracy would be on the last layer by default (keras can't know that you want a specific layer, even autoencoder may not have a middle layer). If you want another metric for the middle layer, you need to specify this explicitly.

Comment: That's exactly my question ... how can I specify it explicitly?

Comment: The question is what metric do you want for the embedded space? There is no truth to the embedded space. Metrics work like a loss, but there is no loss function for the embedded space as you want to find a good one.

Comment: The metric should be accuracy. I think I have to implement a custom metric that gets the true labels as input and trains a simple classifier inside the custom metric to get the predicted outputs. I just don't know how to tell Keras to run the metric on middle layer not the last layer. Do you know any better way?

Comment: As I understand the default accuracy metric in the autoencoder is meaningless, right?

Comment: OK, so you have another classifier, another layer here, which you can now train.

Comment: You may want to edit the question add the classification aspect.

Comment: You mean I have to implement another classifier network containing the encoder freezed for training?

Comment: It's a choice, you don't have to freeze it, you can probably train the autoencoder only first, and then update it while training the classifier.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you really want is a multiple output network.

So on top of your middle layer that defines your embedding, add a layer (or more) to do your classification.

Then have a look at [Multiple outputs in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036971/multiple-outputs-in-keras) to create your global cost.

You may also want to start by training the autoendoder only, then the classifier additional layers only to see the performance, you can also balance the accuracy of the encoder vs the accuracy of the classifier as a loss, training "both" networks at the same time.

Comment: I don't want the classifier network to affect my encoder. I want to use pure reconstruction error as loss function and just monitor the classification accuracy of the middle layer.

Comment: To classify, you still need an additional layer and train it.

Comment: I know. I mean freezing the encoder part and training the rest of the classifier.

Comment: I'm confused, sometimes you want to use the metric during autoencoder training, and sometimes after when training classification :/ You probably need to train both at the same time if you want to have accuracy on the classification during the training of the autoencoder.

Comment: What you said if I understood correctly is a network with one input and two outputs where the input is connected to the encoder, the first output is connected to the decoder and the second output is connected to the classifier. My point is I don't want the error of the classifier be propagated backwards to the encoder. In other words, I want the encoder to be learned only by the error of the decoder (reconstruction error). I want the classifier just to provide a metric and not for training the encoder (it will only train the classifier not the encoder).

Comment: In each epoch of the training of the autoencoder (the encoder and decoder) I want the classifier to be trained fully to get the accuracy as a metric.

Comment: You probably need to fine tune the model, I don't know about keras enough to know how you can train the autoencoder, traint he classifier with the autoencoder frozen, and then compute metrics. Easy to do with tensorflow, but it's a lower level than keras.