# How can I put multiple output for keras DL training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to make a network that uses multiple output. 
 For example, I want to put an input of list which has the shape of : 
 [ 8, 128, 128, 3] 
 Here, 8 is number of images in one set of input, 128 x 128 x 3 is shape of a color image. 
 And I want my output to be : 
 [ 8, 128, 128]
 Here, 8 is number of images in one set of output, 128 x 128 is shape of a gray image.

So I made my code as following :

```
f_list = []
for i in range(v):
    img_in = M.Input((h, w, 3))  # Input :
    feature = spm.encoder(img_in)
    f_list.append(feature)
fuse_ave,fuse_max,fuse_min = spm.fusion(f_list)
decode_list = []
for i in range(v):
    ffuse = spm.decoder(f_list[i],fuse_ave,fuse_max)
    decode_list.append(ffuse)
dl_con = L.concatenate(decode_list,0)
print(dl_con.shape)
epsnet = M.Model(inputs = img_in,outputs = dl_con)
epsnet.compile(optimizer=O.Adam(lr=0.0001,decay = 0.000001), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
epsnet.fit(iml,np.array(gml),batch_size = 5, epochs=50,verbose=1,shuffle=True, validation_split=0.1)
```

Here, the function decode is as following :

```
def decoder(input,fuse_a,fuse_M):    #input : encoded
    infu = L.Concatenate(-1)([input,fuse_a,fuse_M])
    f=128
    x = L.Conv2DTranspose(filters = f,kernel_size=(5,5),strides=2,padding = 'same')(infu)   dding = 'same')(x__)

          ...

    x__ = L.BatchNormalization()(x__)
    x__ = L.Activation('relu')(x__)
    def sq(x):
        x_sq = B.squeeze(x,-1)
        return x_sq
    xq = L.Lambda(sq)(x__)
    return xq
```

Here I am getting error message :

```
 ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("concatenate_7/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, ?), dtype=float32)
```

I tried several ways, but I still get same error message. Please give me a breakthrough and thank you very much.

Comment: please check here , this questions has an already answered here !https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036971/multiple-outputs-in-keras

Comment: Thanks. I solved my problem referring that

Comment: It's my pleasure. @MooNChilD Song