# keras-rl model with multiple outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I want to build a reinforcement learning model with keras which needs to have two outputs. can it be done the same way that the Keras library does or is it even doable?

this is what I want to do

```
inp = Input(shape=(input_layer_size, ))
x = Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation="relu")(inp)
for i in range(nb_hidden_layer):
    x = Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation="relu")(x)
a1 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
a2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple outputs in Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036971/multiple-outputs-in-keras)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is possible, just use:

```
model = Model(inp, [a1,a2])
```

and pay attention to the order of your outputs to don't mistaken them.