# Saving Keras model with multiple outputs (The wrapped dictionary was modified outside the wrapper)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have a multi-class classifier that I also want to query for the output of one of the intermediate layers.

```
inputs = Input(...)

...

fc = Dense(32, activation='relu', name='FC_1')(layer)
x = Dense(num_cats, activation='softmax', name='Softmax')(fc)

outputs = {
    'predictions': x,
    'fc': fc,
}

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

opt = Adam()
cat_crossentropy = SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()


loss = {
    'predictions': cat_crossentropy,
}


model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=loss, metrics={'predictions': [
    SparseCategoricalAccuracy(),
    SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=3),
]})
```

This works great while in the same process. `model.fit()` does what you'd expect, and `model.predict()` returns `outputs` with the values for the two keys defined.

However, `model.save(output_path)` raises the following exception:

```
ValueError: Unable to save the object {
   'predictions': <keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x15e5c6c70>,
   'dense': None,
}

(a dictionary wrapper constructed automatically on attribute assignment).

The wrapped dictionary was modified outside the wrapper (its final value was

{
   'predictions': <keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy object at 0x15e5c6c70>,
   'dense': None
},

its value when a checkpoint dependency was added was None),
which breaks restoration on object creation.

If you don't need this dictionary checkpointed,
wrap it in a non-trackable object; it will be subsequently ignored.
```

## Question

How do I exported a saved model containing named outputs?

## Edit - reproducible code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.data import Dataset
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import SparseCategoricalAccuracy
from tensorflow.keras.losses import SparseCategoricalCrossentropy


def build_model():
    i = Input(shape=(5,))
    fc = Dense(5, activation='relu')(i)
    softmax = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='Softmax')(fc)

    outputs = {'predictions': softmax, 'dense': fc}
    return Model(inputs=i, outputs=outputs)


model = build_model()
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.003)

model.compile(optimizer=opt, metrics={'predictions': [SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]}, loss={
    'predictions': SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)
})

_ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.random.rand(10, 5), np.random.randint(0, 5, 10)))
model.fit(_ds.batch(32), epochs=3, verbose=0)

print(model.predict([[0.1] * 5]))
# >>> {
#       'predictions': array([[
#                               0.20790772,
#                               0.18233214,
#                               0.18703228,
#                               0.20266992,
#                               0.22005796
#                      ]], dtype=float32),
#       'dense': array([[
#                         0.1394624,
#                         0.16406271,
#                         0.,
#                         0.,
#                         0.
#                      ]], dtype=float32)}

model.save('my_model')
# >>> Traceback (most recent call last): ...
```

Comment: This looks like a fun problem.  Can you share re-producible code and I'll try and solve it?

Comment: @PritamDodeja edited to add reproducible code

Comment: Hi @rodrigo-silveira, I got the model to work.  Hope the solution works for you, let me know if it doesn't.  I'm not too strong on metrics and loss functions, so I may have solved this in a naive way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution and a gotcha.

## Solution

The solution is simple: instead of omitting keys in the `losses` dict used in `model.compile` for outputs that don't need a loss (intermediate layers), add the key pointing at a `null` value.

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics={'predictions': [
        SparseCategoricalAccuracy(),
        SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=3)
    ]},
    loss={
        'predictions': SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
        'fc': None,
    #   ^^^^^^^^^^^
    #   The solution
    })
```

Now the output of `model.predict()` is a dict with the same keys as in `model.outputs`. Loading the model with `tf.keras.models.load_model()` just works.

## Gotcha

In Tensorflow Serving, when you perform inference, the output will be a dict whose values are the `Layer.name` values in the layers referenced in `model.outputs`.

```
# Layer names: ("FC_1", "Softmax")
fc = Dense(32, activation='relu', name='FC_1')(layer)
x = Dense(num_cats, activation='softmax', name='Softmax')(fc)

# Keys in model.outputs: ("predictions", "fc")
outputs = {
    'predictions': x,
    'fc': fc,
}

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

When you evaluate the model via Tensorflow Serving, the output will be of the form:

```
{
    "outputs": {
        "Softmax": [ [ 0.1, ... ] ],
        "FC_1": [ [...] ]
    }
}
```

You can also see what the model's output layers are in Tensorflow Serving using the `/v1/models/{modelId}/versions/1/metadata` REST endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, let me know if it works for you.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036971/multiple-outputs-in-keras) helped me figure it out.

```
import tensorflow as tf                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
from tensorflow.data import Dataset                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
from tensorflow.keras import Model, Input                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import SparseCategoricalAccuracy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
from tensorflow.keras.losses import SparseCategoricalCrossentropy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
def build_model():                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    i = Input(shape=(5,))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    fc = Dense(5, activation='relu')(i)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    softmax = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='Softmax')(fc)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    # outputs = {'predictions': softmax, 'dense': fc}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    left_output = softmax                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    right_output = fc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    return Model(inputs=i, outputs=[left_output, right_output])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
model = build_model()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.003)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
# model.compile(optimizer=opt, metrics={'predictions': [SparseCategoricalAccuracy()]}, loss={                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#     'predictions': SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
# })                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
model.compile(optimizer=opt, metrics="SparseCategoricalAccuracy", loss=[SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False)])                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
_ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.random.rand(10, 5), np.random.randint(0, 5, 10)))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
model.fit(_ds.batch(32), epochs=3, verbose=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
print(type(model.predict([[0.1] * 5])))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
print(model.predict([[0.1] * 5]))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
# >>> {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
#       'predictions': array([[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
#                               0.20790772,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#                               0.18233214,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#                               0.18703228,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#                               0.20266992,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#                               0.22005796                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
#                      ]], dtype=float32),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
#       'dense': array([[                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
#                         0.1394624,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
#                         0.16406271,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
#                         0.,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#                         0.,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
#                         0.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
#                      ]], dtype=float32)}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
model.save('my_model')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
# >>> Traceback (most recent call last): ...
```

Output

> Epoch 1/3
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 207ms/step - loss: 1.7489 - >Softmax_loss: 1.7489 - Softmax_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.3000 - >dense_4_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.4000
> Epoch 2/3
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 1.7379 - >Softmax_loss: 1.7379 - Softmax_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.3000 - >dense_4_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.4000
> Epoch 3/3
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 920us/step - loss: 1.7271 - >Softmax_loss: 1.7271 - Softmax_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.3000 - >dense_4_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.4000
> WARNING:tensorflow:5 out of the last 7 calls to Model.make_predict_function..predict_function at >0x7f229d14df70> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive >and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating >@tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different >shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), >please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), >@tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes >argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please >refer to >https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#controlling_retracing and >https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more >details.
> <class 'list'>
> [array([[0.1952633 , 0.19603369, 0.18926372, 0.2137877 , >0.20565161]],
> dtype=float32), array([[0.12314494, 0.        , 0.13512844, 0.        >, 0.        ]],
> dtype=float32)]
> INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: my_model/assets

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. I think you left off the code where you compile the model, though.

Comment: Adding it as soon as I figure out this editing thing.  I seriously need to get better at copying-pasting.

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira it's updated now.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. Looks like using a list of outputs saves the model (haven't tried loading it), but it's still not quite what I need. In my case, I'd like intuitive access to several intermediate layers. Having to remember index offset is not ideal

Comment: Looks like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JN08CqZKKkA solves it the same way for a multi-output problem.  As far as the access to intermediate layers, can you clarify what you mean?  Is this your model architecture in your reproducible code or is there some other missing complexity?  As it's a softmax on the left side, doesn't it need to be interpreted as summing up to 1 and indicative of probability? And the dense layer is hidden layer you're referencing which is the right_output?  In any case, if there's any info missing, let me know.  I want to solve some hard problems.  Thanks!